# Выбрать уникальные значения в БД по ключу

Tags: php

Дано: база данных со 1000 записями. Необходимо вывести эти записи в случайном порядке, но сохранить возможность повторить этот случайный порядок, дабы его можно было вызвать еще раз в той же последовательности

Решение 1: предварительно сгенерировать порядки / сохранять порядки в бд

Есть более элегантное решение?

Answer (score 4):

Можно сортировать на лету по какой либо хеш функции (например md5) от данных записи (лучше взять ID) и некого числа/строки (далее "соль"), которая будет как раз задавать порядок. Если передаете в запрос одно и то же значение соли то получаете те же самые значения хеша, а следовательно и порядок записей будет тот же.

```
select *
  from table
 order by md5(concat(id, 'соль'))
```